# How to line-wrap console output in NetBeans 6.8?

Tags: netbeans, console, word-wrap

Is there a way to make the console output text wrap based on the actual width of the window?
I have limited screen height real estate on my laptop, and so want to have the console window docked on the right rather than the bottom of the window.

An option or a plugin is fine, I'm using NetBeans 6.8. If this exists in a newer version of NetBeans, please say so, but I can't install a dev build.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do a right-click on the Output console and check 'Wrap Text', and it adjusts itself according to Output window width.